# Change the color of a text in div using jquery contains

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Here the whole text inside the div get's red color. but I need only the "bar" word color to be changed

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
    <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
     <head>
      <title> new document </title>
     <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
     <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function(){
            $("#foo:contains('bar')").css('color','red');
        });
     </script>
     </head>
     <body>
    <div id="foo">
        this is a new bar 
    </div>
     </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: You'll need to surround `bar` with another element.

Comment: ya, like a span (display inline)

Comment: Yes you guys are right but these values are attained dynamically in such cases what i need to do

Comment: You need to split the text into parts, and put “bar” inside an element of its own. Whether you do that using innerHTML and string functions/regex, or using DOM methods, is up to you.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Could be done like that:

http://jsfiddle.net/PELkt/

```
var search = 'bar';
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("div:contains('"+search+"')").each(function () {
        var regex = new RegExp(search,'gi');
        $(this).html($(this).text().replace(regex, "<span class='red'>"+search+"</span>"));
    });
});
```

Comment: The `i` flag makes this solution case insensitive.

Answer (score 6):

```
$("div:contains('bar')").each(function () {
    $(this).html($(this).html().replace("bar", "<span class='red'>bar</span>"));
});
```

this will work surely

Please see **[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/5bSgc/2/)** Here

Answer (score 2):

You can use this way :

```
       $(document).ready(function(){
               //  $("#foo:contains('bar')").css('color','red');
               var text = 'bar' ;
               var  context = $("#foo").html();
               $("#foo").html(context.replace(text,'<span style="color:red;">'+text+'</span>'));
        });
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this... [prototype](http://prototypejs.org/) library:

```
<html> 
<head> 

    <style type="text/css">
        #content span {
            background-color: yellow;
        }
    </style>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="prototype.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        Event.observe(window,'load',function(){
            var htm = $('content').innerHTML;
            $('content').innerHTML = htm.sub('bar','<font color=red>bar</font>');
        });
    </script>
</head>
<body>

    <div id="content">
        this is a new bar
    </div>

</body>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do like this.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    var matchingTest = 'demo';
    $("#container:contains("+matchingTest+")").each(function () {
     $(this).html($(this).html().replace(matchingTest, "<span class='red'>"+matchingTest+"</span>"));
    });
});
```

```css
.red{
  background:#eada93;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="container">
  Hello this is a demo contents.
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Solution with code snippet..

```js
var text_change = 'bar';
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("div:contains('"+text_change+"')").each(function () {
        var regex = new RegExp(text_change,'gi');
        $(this).html($(this).text().replace(regex, "<span class='red'>"+text_change+"</span>"));
    });
});
```

```css
.red {
    color:#008000;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="text">this is a new bar and bar.</div>
```