# jquery find and replace a word in string to make it bold between estaric and

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

Is there any library or custom function which can find the text and make it bold i.e wiki text to html works. Actually I want to process a text which should work the way whatsapp and skype works.

```
var textString = "A text which should be *bold*  _Italic_  and ~Strike~ ";
```

I want it to bold the word bold and italic to word italic with jquery on the basis of *,_ and ~ sign

Comment: You can use regex under a div.
This may help you-- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17232820/change-the-color-of-a-text-in-div-using-jquery-contains

Comment: @Ali Look at https://github.com/sankalp179/whatsapp-formatter/blob/master/index.html. Also, demo is available at https://sankalp179.github.io/whatsapp-formatter/

Answer (score 2):

```js
let textString = "A text which should be *bold*  _Italic_  and ~Strike~ ";

const check = [{
  reg: /\*(.*)\*/gm,
  class: 'bold'
}, {
  reg: /_(.*)_/gm,
  class: 'italic'
}, {
  reg: /~(.*)~/gm,
  class: 'strike'
}];
let newStr = '';
check.map(x => {
  const regx = x.reg.exec(textString);
  const replace = "<span class='" + x.class + "'>" + regx[1] + "</span>";
  const spl = textString.split(regx[0]);
  newStr = spl[0] + replace + spl[1];
  textString = newStr;
});
document.getElementById('foo').innerHTML = newStr;
```

```css
.italic{
  font-style: italic;
}

.strike {
  text-decoration: line-through;
}

.bold {
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

```html
<div id="foo"><div>
```